# Differentiate between Gitlab webhook events

Tags: automation, gitlab, webhooks, merge-request, git-webhooks

Is there a way to differentiate between Gitlab webhook events, specifically `merge_request` events with the action `update`.

It seems like the payload for (lets say) a Label change is the same as marking the MR as ready.

Just checking the values of the fields `work_in_progress` or `draft` does not seem sufficient, because an edit can also be made to a non-draft MR.

So my question is, what are the attribute indicators for "mark as ready"? Also interesting would be something similar for "resolved all threads".

Thanks in advance.

I am referencing following documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhook_events.html#merge-request-events

Comment: There's a "changes" object in the JSON. Within that, you can use "draft", `"previous": true,"current": false` as an indication of "mark as ready", but I'm not sure there is one for things like "resolved all thread". Certainly, you can see if the latest update includes comments and the merge_status

Comment: @Arty-chan thanks, but "previous" and "current" seems to be always "null" in my case, do you know what this means and whether I have to activate some settings?

Comment: it should be when specifically something goes from being marked as draft to marked as ready but admittedly, I haven't testing this recently